# What does != mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am mainly trying to figure out what this function is trying to say. For the most part I understand that the function is checking the variables and seeing if they are indeed variables.  But what does != say in the script?

```
function fun2() {
  var output = "";

  if (typeof myGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += "myGlobal: " + myGlobal;
  }

  if (typeof oopsGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += " oopsGlobal: " + oopsGlobal;
  }

  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: `!=` means not equal to. Your code is checking if value is available

Comment: Have you looked it up, maybe checked the MDN page of operators?

Comment: You should follow some basic tutorials on internet before asking question like this here

Comment: This is very readily available information online, not worth a question here.

Comment: Did you do a research about that ?

Comment: Its a comparison operator. Please read about them, it will make programming make allot more sense. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: ok yea, i forgot where it was in my notes.  That the one that is true if they are not true. lol XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `!=` means if is different for example `red != blue` it return true, you can check the documentation of expressions and operators here:
[Comparison_operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators) Dev Mozilla JS